# Where are Falcon 9 1st stage GN2 tanks located?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, propulsion, rcs

Is nitrogen propellant for the two cold gas thrusters pods contained in the interstage? The view we have from the B5-B1050 recovery shows several small COPV(s)
[pic1](https://images.app.goo.gl/vPk5CR9F1nifEhRF9)

Here you can see where the cold gas thrusters might be on top with what look like lines running in from the top right. The COPV slightly to the left looks unrelated. Granted the interstage is missing a lot of hardware.
[pic2](https://images.app.goo.gl/6SNo7sPNkrASeaYS6)